# Nested bootstrap grid breaks when wrapped in a form tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The nested grid thumbnails on this page do not nest correctly. The page has to be wrapped in a  tag in order to submit the results to wufoo. If I change the wrapping form tag to a div tag the nested grid thumbnails work correctly. Any thoughts? http://thehomeshare.com/view2 [image]

**this is the desired layout**

[image]

Comment: The Bootstrap form elements have certain grid/layout styles applied which allow for things like ".form-group" to function identically to ".row"s. This could be causing problems with nested element padding which cause your layout to not fit in the container. You would have to provide more info for your questions to be better answered though IMO.

Comment: If you post your actual HTML in the question that will be easier for us to evaluate rather than an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently inline-list grid functionality doesn't work when wrapped in a form tag.

I removed the container ul and changed the li's to divs and it worked like a charm

```
 <ul class="inline-list">
     <li class="col-xs-6"......
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of conflicting issues with the grid layout.  I've also added some CSS classes to your code.  I have a jsfiddle so you can see what I've done to partially resolve the issues you are having.

[Access the DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/qd8ez3hc/)

Here's a portion of you code, but I basically added the CSS class="img-responsive" to your main image and the "col-xs-6" to the columns:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><!--  I'VE ADDED THE "col-xs-6" TO THE DIV  -->
            <img src="http://thehomeshare.com/assets/potrero1010/1200-4a9580217f67077603e917338f4d2ffd4e9e5951910f809f2e2fe97e0b4ba6bb.png" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="img-responsive"><!--  I'VE ADDED THE class="img-responsive" TO THE IMAGE  -->
```

You can replicate the same technique to the other options. I hope this shed some light to the grid conflicting issues you are having.!